# Laravel Spark, Swap/Interact, and Private Variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-spark

Using Laravel Spark, if I wanted to swap in a new implementation for the `configureTeamForNewUser`, at first it looks like it's possible because of the `Spark::interact` call here

```
#File: spark/src/Interactions/Auth/Register.php
Spark::interact(self::class.'@configureTeamForNewUser', [$request, $user]);
```

i.e. the framework calls `configureTeamForNewUser` using `Spark::interact`, which means I can `Spark::swap` it.

However, if I look at the `configureTemForNewUser` method itself

```
#File: spark/src/Interactions/Auth/Register.php
public function configureTeamForNewUser(RegisterRequest $request, $user)
{
    if ($invitation = $request->invitation()) {
        Spark::interact(AddTeamMember::class, [$invitation->team, $user]);

        self::$team = $invitation->team;

        $invitation->delete();
    } elseif (Spark::onlyTeamPlans()) {
        self::$team = Spark::interact(CreateTeam::class, [
            $user, ['name' => $request->team, 'slug' => $request->team_slug]
        ]);
    }

    $user->currentTeam();
}
```

This method assigns a value to the private `$team` class property. It's my understanding that if I use `Spark::swap` my callback is called instead of the original method.  Initial tests confirm this.  However, since my callback can't set `$team`, this means my callback would change the behavior of the system in a way that's going to break other spark functionality.

Is the above a correct understanding of the system?  Or am I missing something, and it would be possible to `swap` in another function call (somehow calling the original `configureTeamForNewUser`)?

Answer (score -1):

Of course, you can swap this `configureTeamForNewUser` method. Spark create a team for a user at the registration. You have to add the swap method inside the `Booted()` method of App/Providers/SparkServiceProvider.php class.
in the top use following,

```
use Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Interactions\Auth\Register;
use Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Http\Requests\Auth\RegisterRequest;
use Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Interactions\Settings\Teams\CreateTeam;
use Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Interactions\Settings\Teams\AddTeamMember;
```

In my case I want to add new field call "custom_one" to the teams table. Inside the `booted()` method, swap the method as bellow.

```
Spark::swap('Register@configureTeamForNewUser', function(RegisterRequest $request, $user){
if ($invitation = $request->invitation()) {
 Spark::interact(AddTeamMember::class, [$invitation->team, $user]);
   self::$team = $invitation->team;
   $invitation->delete();
 } elseif (Spark::onlyTeamPlans()) {
   self::$team = Spark::interact(CreateTeam::class, [ $user, 
         [
            'name' => $request->team,
            'slug' => $request->team_slug,
            'custom_one' => $request->custom_one, 
         ] ]);
}
  $user->currentTeam();
});
```

In order to add a new custom_one field, I had to swap the `TeamRepository@create`method as well. After swapping `configureTeamForNewUser` method, swap the TeamRepository@create method onside the booted(),

```
Spark::swap('TeamRepository@create', function ($user,  $data) {
                $attributes = [
                    'owner_id' => $user->id,
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'custom_one' => $data['custom_one'],
                    'trial_ends_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(Spark::teamTrialDays()),
                ];

            if (Spark::teamsIdentifiedByPath()) {
                $attributes['slug'] = $data['slug'];
            }
            return Spark::team()->forceCreate($attributes);
        });
```

Then proceed with your registration.

See [Laravel Spark documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/4.0/customization)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. However, it seems I failed to correctly emphasize what I was asking. While your examples will run, the self::$team references in your code will reference the provider class variables and not the static class $team variable on the AddTeamMember class. This means is when other methods in the AddTeamMember try to access self::$team, self::$team will not be set.